# unhashable type 'list' when i enter on change_list in Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-queryset

I search for days for a solution for this problem. after touching the admin.py file to override the get_queryset and get_form methods I ran into the unhashable type 'list' error, which has no information on where the error is located. I removed the override for the get_queryset and get_form methods, but I still get the same result.

**[The error]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'**

I find this error when I want to filter a list by overriding the get_queryset method or when I try to enter an element of the form's list.
The files in my project are as follows:

APP => Main

admin.py

```
@admin.register(Notification)
class NotificationsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, ExportCsvMixin):
    form = NotificationForm
    add_form = NotificationForm

    list_display = ('title', 'description', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
                    'author')
    fieldsets = (
        ('Information', {
            'fields':
            ('author', 'title', 'subject', 'description', 'signature')
        }),
        ('Images', {
            'fields': ('banner', 'image', 'image2', 'image3')
        }),
        ('Send to', {
            'fields': (
                'send_to',
                'send_all',
            )
        }),
        ('Logs', {
            'fields': ('created_at', 'updated_at')
        }),
    )

    readonly_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at')
    actions = ['export_as_csv']
    list_per_page = 20

    # list_max_show_all = 30

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):

        if request.user.groups.filter(name="RSM's").exists():
            self.readonly_fields = ('author', 'created_at', 'updated_at')

        else:
            self.readonly_fields = (
                'created_at',
                'updated_at',
            )
        form = super(NotificationsAdmin, self).get_form(request, **kwargs)

        form.current_user = request.user

        return form

    # get_queryset will return the list of notifications of the user author RSM, else, return all the notifications
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(NotificationsAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.groups.filter(name="RSM's").exists():
            return qs.filter(author=request.user.id)
        else:
            return qs


# Business Segment
# Business Segment
@admin.register(BusinessSegment)
class BusinessSegmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, ExportCsvMixin):
    change_form = BusinessSegmentForm

    list_display = ('name', 'status', 'default_view',
                    'total_visible_companies', 'total_companies',
                    'description', 'get_created_at')
    search_fields = ('name', 'status', 'companies')
    fieldsets = (
        ('General', {
            'fields': ('name', 'description', 'img', 'alt_text')
        }),
        ('Companies', {
            'fields': ('companies', )
        }),
        ('Status and View', {
            'fields': ('status', 'default_view')
        }),
        ('Block Views', {
            'fields': ('blocked_countries', )
        }),
    )
    actions = ['export_as_csv']
    list_per_page = 20
    # list_max_show_all = 30

    ordering = [
        'name',
    ]


# Company Space
@admin.register(CompanySpace)
class CompanySpaceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, ExportCsvMixin):

    list_display = ('name', 'status', 'default_view', 'business_area',
                    'website_url', 'get_created_at', 'button_post')
    search_fields = ('name', 'status', 'company_classification',
                     'business_area', 'default_view')
    fieldsets = (('Company Information', {
        'fields': ('name', 'slogan', 'description', 'mini_banner', 'banner',
                   'country', 'business_area')
    }), ('Status and View', {
        'fields': (
            'status',
            'default_view',
        )
    }), ('Presentation or Corporate Brochure', {
        'fields': (
            'brochure_name',
            'brochure',
            'technical_file_name',
            'technical_file',
            'technical_file_name2',
            'technical_file2',
            'technical_file_name3',
            'technical_file3',
            'technical_file_name4',
            'technical_file4',
            'technical_file_name5',
            'technical_file5',
            'technical_file_name6',
            'technical_file6',
            'technical_file_name7',
            'technical_file7',
            'technical_file_name8',
            'technical_file8',
            'technical_file_name9',
            'technical_file9',
            'technical_file_name10',
            'technical_file10',
            'technical_file_name11',
            'technical_file11',
            'technical_file_name12',
            'technical_file12',
        )
    }), ('Videos', {
        'fields': (
            'name_video',
            'url_video',
            'video_language1',
            'name_video2',
            'url_video2',
            'video_language2',
            'name_video3',
            'url_video3',
            'video_language3',
            'name_video4',
            'url_video4',
            'video_language4',
            'name_video5',
            'url_video5',
            'video_language5',
        )
    }), ('Website URL', {
        'fields': ('website_url', )
    }), ('Block Views', {
        'fields': ('blocked_countries', )
    }))
    actions = [
        'export_as_csv',
    ]
    list_per_page = 20
    # list_max_show_all = 12

    ordering = [
        'name',
    ]

    # Faltante que el boton solo aparezca una sola vez, cuando se postea por primera vez la compañia
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            path('post_company/<int:pk>/',
                 self.post_company,
                 name="admin_post_company"),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls

    def post_company(self, request, pk):
        context = dict(
            # Include common variables for rendering the admin template.
            self.admin_site.each_context(request),
            # Anything else you want in the context...
        )

        company = get_object_or_404(CompanySpace, pk=pk)

        if company:
            if company.status == 'Closed':
                company.status = 'Open'
                company.save()
                if company.default_view == True:
                    clients = Client.objects.all()

                    # ENVIO EMAIL A CLIENTE
                    for client in clients:
                        # SUBJECT
                        subject_client = f'New Manufacturer @ YEM\'s Reserved Area'
                        # MESSAGE TEMPLATE
                        message_client = get_template(
                            "emails/new-sponsor.html").render({
                                'company': company,
                                'url': settings.BASE_URL,
                                'client': client,
                            })

                        mail_client = EmailMessage(
                            subject=subject_client,
                            body=message_client,
                            from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                            to=[client.email],
                        )
                        mail_client.content_subtype = "html"
                        mail_client.send()

                msg = f'Success: Post Company'
                self.message_user(request, msg, level=messages.INFO)
                return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

        else:
            msg = f'Company is null'
            self.message_user(request, msg, level=messages.INFO)
            return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
        return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

models.py

```
# Company space
class CompanySpace(models.Model):
    """
    Company space model.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS, default='Closed')
    default_view = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    company_classification = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="")
    slogan = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000, default="")
    mini_banner = models.ImageField(upload_to="mini_banners/", blank=True)
    banner = models.ImageField(upload_to="empresas/")
    country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)', multiple=True)
    business_area = models.CharField(max_length=80,
                                     choices=BUSINESS_AREA,
                                     default='')
    website_url = models.URLField(max_length=200, default="", blank=True)
    blocked_countries = CountryField(default='Select country',
                                     multiple=True,
                                     null=False,
                                     blank=True)
    first_time = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
        'name',
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_videos(self):
        return self.video_set.all()

    def get_technical_files(self):
        return self.technical_file_set.all()

    def button_post(self):
        company = get_object_or_404(CompanySpace, pk=self.pk)

        if company.status == 'Closed' and company.first_time == True:
            return format_html(
                '<a href="{}" class="btn btn-warning">Post</a>',
                reverse_lazy("admin:admin_post_company", args=[self.pk]))

    button_post.short_description = 'Post company'

    def get_created_at(self):
        return self.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

    get_created_at.short_description = 'Created at'


# Product




class Notification(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey('users.User',
                               verbose_name="Author",
                               related_name="users_User",
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               blank=False,
                               default="")
    banner = models.ImageField(upload_to="notifications/banners/", blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Message")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="notifications/images/",
                              default="",
                              blank=True)
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="notifications/images/",
                               default="",
                               blank=True)
    image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to="notifications/images/",
                               default="",
                               blank=True)
    signature = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # Agregar una forma de MULTISELECTFIELD
    send_to = models.ManyToManyField('users.Client', blank=True)
    send_all = models.BooleanField(default=False,
                                   verbose_name="Send message to all users")
    subject = models.TextField(max_length=1000, default="", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Server logs

```
ERROR:django.request:Internal Server Error: /pre-production/admin/main/businesssegment/1/change/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 195, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 172, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 214, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 315, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 195, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 172, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 214, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 214, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 315, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 988, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 671, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 796, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 858, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py", line 239, in contents
    result_repr = display_for_field(value, f, self.empty_value_display)
  File "*****HIDDEN URL******/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py", line 385, in display_for_field
    return dict(field.flatchoices).get(value, empty_value_display)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There's something wrong with your `choices`, which you did not show to us.

Comment: @KlausD. You mean this?
` 
STATUS = (
    ('Closed', 'Closed'),
    ('Open', 'Open'),
)

BUSINESS_AREA = (
    ('Building Automation, Security and Fire Solutions',
     'Building Automation, Security and Fire Solutions'),
    ('Door Automation and Construction Materials',
     'Door Automation and Construction Materials'),
    ('Smart Mobility and Traffic Management',
     'Smart Mobility and Traffic Management'),
    ('Video Analytics, Cybersecurity and Defence',
     'Video Analytics, Cybersecurity and Defence'),
) 
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After delving into the problem, the error was generated in the model form inside a conditional readonly field in the html template. The error was specifically in {{field.contents}} of the fieldsets.html file.
This problem is generated by lack of permissions in the group to which the user was assigned. Once that permission was added, the error disappeared.

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title, question, or answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). For self-answers, you must wait 48 hours to do so in case somebody else suggests a better solution.